# save different objects resulting from a for loop

Tags: r, for-loop, save

I am trying to save different objects resulting from a for loop.

This is my matrix and subsetting that I needed:

```
row.names <- c('A2003','B2010','C2011','D2010','E2001','F2005','F2009','G2003','G2007','H2004','H2010')
sp1 <- c(4,83,1,2,4,3,1,5,7,2,4)
sp2 <- c(5,0,2,3,10,5,0,2,4,3,1)
sp3 <- c(7,2,4,8,7,2,4,83,1,5,7)
sp4 <- c(0,2,4,2,4,12,1,5,7,2,4)
Site <- c('A','B','C','D','E','F','F','G','G','H','H')
Year <- c('2003','2010','2011','2010','2001','2005','2009','2003','2007','2004','2010')
Obs <- c(1,1,1,4,9,6,8,2,5,2,3)
ID <- c('A2003','B2010','C2011','D2010','E2001','F2005','F2009','G2003','G2007','H2004','H2010')
df<- data.frame(row.names, sp1, sp2, sp3, sp4, Site, Year, Obs, ID)
rownames(df) <- df[,1]
df[,1] <- NULL
df
#fix(df)
df.1 <- subset(df, Obs == 1)
df.more <- subset(df, Obs >= 2)
df.1
df.more
```

And here it is the Script for the loop function in which I have problems:

```
N.rows <- nrow(df)
for(i in 1:N.rows){      
  rnd.more <- do.call( rbind, lapply( split(df.more, df.more$Site) ,
                                    function(df.more) df.more[sample(nrow(df.more), 1,replace=FALSE) , ] )  
  )
  print(rnd.more)
  rnd.df <- rbind(df.1,rnd.more)                                   
  rnd.df.bc <- as.matrix(vegdist(rnd.df[1:4], method="bray"))  
  clustering <- agnes(rnd.df.bc, diss=TRUE, method = "ward")        
  print(clustering)
  grps.iter <-cutree(as.hclust(clustering), k=3)                     
  print(grps.iter)
}
```

Problems:

1) The script is not working as I would like in its totality because the 'do.call' function gives me a data frame without keeping the row names. So for the following results I cannot identify my observations.

2) I would like to save the output. If it is not possible doing it at once (they have different forms), maybe separately as "rnd.more", "clustering" and "grps.iter"

I have tried looking into other questions/responses but I did not understand how to do it...

Thanks for your help. Have mercy on me, I'm a self-learning R user... (and not so good!)

Comment: There is no such column as `ont.Obs`.

Comment: I did a mistake @RomanLuštrik . I have updated the script with "Obs"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You've put rownames into the `ID` column. Tracing problem solved.

2) Use a list.

```
library(cluster)
library(vegan)

out <- vector("list", N.rows)
for(i in 1:N.rows){      
    rnd.more <- do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df.more, df.more$Site),
                                        function(df.more) df.more[sample(nrow(df.more), 1,replace=FALSE) , ])
                        )
    rnd.df <- rbind(df.1,rnd.more)                                   
    rnd.df.bc <- as.matrix(vegdist(rnd.df[1:4], method="bray"))  
    clustering <- agnes(rnd.df.bc, diss=TRUE, method = "ward")        
    grps.iter <-cutree(as.hclust(clustering), k=3)                     
    out[[i]] <- list(rnd = rnd.df, clustering = clustering, grps = grps.iter)
}

# see clustering in first element
out[[1]]$clustering

# extract clustering
all.clusters <- lapply(out, "[[", "clustering")
all.clusters
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, @Roman Luštrik.

1) I have eliminated the variable ID from the matrix, letting only row names in the data frame, but I still have the problem at the first command ('do.call'). Automatically the matrix of random observations acquires "Site" as row name.

2) How is out[[i]] exactly computed? It's not clear for me.
Thanks again!

Comment: You will have to leave in the ID to keep your rows traceable. I create an empty list with as many elements as number of rows and add an extra list (of `rnd.df`, `clustering` and `grps.iter`) within each element.

Comment: It worked out! Thanks a lot @Roman Luštrik
Just for being clear if anyone else need it: the first element of the "=" from `out[[i]] <- list(rnd = rnd.df, clustering = clustering, grps = grps.iter)` can be changed by any name. The second one has to coincide with the elements we want to extract.
Then for saving the elements: 
`all.grps.iter <- lapply(out, "[[", "grps")
all.grps.iter
capture.output(all.grps.iter,file="all.grps.iter.txt") # as text file
write.csv(all.grps.iter, file="all.grps.iter.csv") # as csv file`